# Byobu changing tabs

Tags: command-line, byobu

When I'm sharing the same byobu session with multiple users, sometimes when I change the tab, the other user is automatically changed to my new tab, and sometimes he has to do it manually. How can I specify if I want to force the users to change the tab automatically or not?

Answer (score 9):

Other users would need to open their own session.  Then, each user can move around each window or split, on a per session basis.

For navigation hot keys, see the help page with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>:

- <kbd>F2</kbd>                             Create a new window
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>                     Create a horizontal split
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>                      Create a vertical split
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>                Create a new session
- <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd>                          Move focus among windows
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>               Move focus among windows
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>                  Move focus among sessions
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>     Move focus among splits
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F4</kbd>                  Move focus among splits
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F4</kbd>                   Move a split
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F4</kbd>             Move a window
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> Resize a split

Comment: I don't understand your answer... When you say "Other users would need to open their own session" what are you refering to? To be automatically changed from their tabs when I change mine? Or to not being automatically changed?

Comment: @Caumons I think by default, they'd have the same session as you and tabs their would change when you change. Only if they had a different session, would they have to do it manually (either they made and moved to a new session, or you did)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you can enable Meta Key per [1](https://superuser.com/questions/649960/option-key-does-not-work-as-meta-in-tmux) and then switching between tabs w/ `Option` + `Shift` + `Left`